# GeoPandas sjoin giving different results between computers

Tags: geopandas, spatial-join

Coworker and I are getting different results from the same code on the same data. It is a very simple script where the shapefile is imported and converted to 4326, then we import the points and do a spatial join.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

shp = gpd.read_file("shapefile.shp")
shp = shp.to_crs("EPSG:4326")

points = pd.read_csv("points.csv")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(points.lon, points.lat))

sjoin = gdf.sjoin(shp, how='inner')
```

When I run it, I get 59/736 points returned, but my coworker only gets 3/736.

We are both reading in the same points CSV and shapefile from the server and running the exact same code. We restarted our computers, created new environments, and confirmed our versions of GeoPandas, rtree, etc. are all the same. But we still get different results.

Has anyone run into this or something similar? Not sure what to do about it.

-- **Update: Environments** --
My coworker is off today, so I can't get a full 'conda list' from them, but we did previously confirm we have the same versions of the following:

- `python 3.10.1 h9a09f29_2_cpython conda-forge`
- `geopandas 0.10.2 pyhd8ed1ab_0 conda-forge`
- `geopandas-base 0.10.2 pyha770c72_0 conda-forge`
- `pyproj 3.3.0 py38h12f9802_0 conda-forge`
- `rtree 0.9.7 py310h1cbd46b_3 conda-forge`

We built our environments following the exact steps below:

```
conda create --name env2
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

Something interesting though was that the above commands originally returned slightly different environments. My environment was built with pyproj 3.3.0 and their environment was built with pyproj 2.6.1.post1. We thought this could be the problem, but updating to 3.3.0 did not change their results.

-- **Update: Data** --
We both get the same output for `points.shape`, 736x8. I can't currently confirm we get the same output for `shp.shape`, but the count of polygons is very important and they would have raised a flag if it was different from what it should always be. Though I will update once they get back to me.

The 3 points they get are not points I get in my 59.

```
    geometry
284 POINT (-155.47659 19.20657)
285 POINT (-157.72620 21.28898)
286 POINT (-157.72621 21.28953)
```

For some context, these are all points falling very close to the border of a polygon. On my end, these points are not considered to be intersecting the polygon, but on coworker's end they were.

[image]

Comment: `shp.shape` and `points.shape` give the same output for the both of you?

Comment: @BERA yes, we get the same shapes

Comment: Can you share your data with us? Can you please show the result of `print(gdf)` just before the join procedure?

Comment: can you also provide the output of `pip freeze` and `python -V` for both computers ? even if both are the same it would be helpful for triaging exactly which version of the code ks being run

Comment: @Taras sorry, I am not able to share the data at the moment, but I can check.

Comment: Are all the points essentially intersecting the boundaries? If so, it seems like it might be a precision issue. On different computer hardware the transformation to 4326 could have different results past five or so decimal places, which could randomly place the points inside or outside the polygons if they are extremely close to the polygon boundary.

Comment: I was allowed to run the script through Google Colab, where I installed geopandas (0.10.2), rtree (0.9.7), and fiona (1.8.20) through pip, instead of building a conda environment. The results I got matched that of my coworker, the 3 points. This leads me to believe the issue is on my end. Perhaps something external of my environment is causing the issue. Maybe ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: This might sound silly, but just wanted to check something really small: when you ran the second `conda` command (`conda install ...`), are you sure that you were doing so in the newly-created `env2`? Because if you just typed `conda create ...` and then `conda install ...`, you might have installed `geopandas` on the `root` environment, not on the `env2` environment. Did you type `conda activate env2` between the two conda commands above?

Comment: @FelipeD. not silly! Everything is worth checking at this point. But I did install to the new environment. I am actually unable to make changes to the base environment.

Comment: Great! Thanks! By the way, what is your objective with the `sjoin`? Do you just want to find the points-to-polygon pairings? If that's what you're trying to do and the points on the borders are giving you some trouble, you can try applying a small buffer to the polygons to ensure that the points actually get captured by the polygons. If that doesn't work, you can also calculate the distances between all points and polygons and just select the closest polygon to every point (within some acceptable distance threshold).

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of confusion, we figured it out it was probably being caused by a caching issue between Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Notebook. Once the notebook had been run in Jupyter Lab and returned 59 points, creating a new environment or running in Jupyter Notebook would not change the output. However, if I created a new environment without defaults, only installed geopandas and then installed Notebook through Anaconda Navigator, I would get the 3 points.

At the end of the day I still don't know the exact cause, by I felt the easiest fix was to just start from scratch. I uninstalled Anaconda and Python, and re-installed. Now we are getting the same results.